# How to make textblock blink|flash in C# for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've a page MainPage.xaml that has a textbox and a button for transition for page1.xaml, in my page mainpage.cs i have a method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string newUrl = "/Page1.xaml?text=" + textoInput.Text;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(newUrl, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In my Page1.xaml i have a textblock that will be the text that was placed in textbox at MainPage.xaml.
At my Page1.cs i have a method:

```
string textBoxValue = "";
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    //Retrieve the value passed during page navigation
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("text", out textBoxValue);
    textBlockTexto.Text = textBoxValue;     
}
```

My question is how do I make my textblock (text.BlockTexto.Text) infinitely flash

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Storyborad` with `ColorAnimation`. Here is [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx).

Change `StackPanel` to `TextBox` and it will animate background for you. Here is a sample for TextBox with animtaion on tap:

```
<TextBox TextBox_Tap="Textbox_Tapped" Text="MyText">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
        <!-- Animate the background color of the canvas from red to green over 4 seconds. -->
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mySolidColorBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="Red" To="Green" Duration="0:0:4" />
        </Storyboard>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="mySolidColorBrush" Color="Red" />
    </TextBox.Background>
</StackPanel>
```

How to call animation:

```
// When the user taps the textbox, the animation begins.
private void TextBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e){
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

I would not recommend you to loop the animation infinitely, because isn't in design guideline and eats battery due to high load on GPU/CPU of mobile device.